# Getting an error when trying to save a table entry

Tags: ruby, cassandra, cequel

I have a problem when trying to create a simple list of projects.
First I defined the model with three columns which should belong to a compound key.

```
class Project
  include Cequel::Record

  key :client, :text, { partition: true }
  key :type, :text, { partition: true }
  key :dep, :text, { partition: true }

end
```

Later when I try to create the Project via

```
project = Project.create!({client: "test", type: "test", dep: "test"})
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/cequel-1.6.1/lib/cequel/record/callbacks.rb:34:in `save': undefined method `batch' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The error message is not very descriptive. Can someone help here?

---edit----

I have found the problem. After connecting, I have to set set class member of Cequel::Record.

```
connection = Cequel::connect(config);
Cequel::Record.connection = connection
```

This is probably because I don't use rails but only normal ruby.
Now I ran into another problem. The tables are not created automatically with `Project.create!` but I have to create the table manually first:

```
  connection.schema.create_table(:projects) do 
    partition_key :client, :text
    partition_key :type, :text
    partition_key :dept, :text
  end
```

But this syntax is different from the documented Record definition and I only found it by sifting through the source code. But this creates two problems.

- Code overhead
- I don't know the syntax for `has_many` and `belongs_to` so I cannot create the table correctly if the Record includes this

Am I overlooking a method to create the table automatically from the `Project` class definition?

Comment: You really need to dig through the complete stack-trace to see where that goes awry. It could be a bug in the gem.